# How To Know One View Is Touches Other View In Ios

Tags: ios, animation, view, touch

I want to know when my Views are touch each other at any position[image: This Is Image That Give You Better Idea About The My Proble]

Thank You In Advance.

Comment: you can handle by touchesBegan Delegate  or add  gesture on View1

Comment: U can check that by using x and y position of that view

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIKit Dynamics for this.
In your viewController add following lines.

```
UIDynamicAnimator* animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

UICollisionBehavior* collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1]];


[animator addBehavior:collision];

// add a boundary that coincides with the top edge
CGPoint topEdge = CGPointMake(view2.frame.origin.x +
                            view2.frame.size.width, view2.frame.origin.y);

[collision addBoundaryWithIdentifier:@"view2"
                        fromPoint:view2.frame.origin
                          toPoint:topEdge];
```

Now in your viewcontroller add this delegate **UICollisionBehaviorDelegate**
and set **collision.collisionDelegate = self;**

You can get the collision notification in following method

```
- (void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior *)behavior beganContactForItem:(id<UIDynamicItem>)item 
        withBoundaryIdentifier:(id<NSCopying>)identifier atPoint:(CGPoint)p {
NSLog(@"Boundary contact occurred - %@", identifier);
}
```

Comment: Can You Please Give Me More Detail How To apply My Code In This.

Comment: simply put this code in your viewController and replace your view's names with view1 and view2.

Comment: you can also use like this, if you don't want to specify a collision boundary.

collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view1, view2]];

Comment: Is this helpful to you? Or else you can provide your code.

Comment: in my code i have two view view1 is coming from up side and view 2 is at bottom and view2 can be move around and i want to check that view1 is touches the view2 or not

Comment: i have two frame of both view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101043/discussion-between-hardik-vyas-and-rushi-sangani).

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help  you.
You can check by using `CGRectIntersectsRect` to check that two views intersect each other or not.

```
-(BOOL)isView: (UIView *) view1 IntersectsWithOtherView:(UIView*)view2 {

if(CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)){

    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

Comment: It's Only Check the X,Y means it's only check for Top Left Corner Is Touching or not

Comment: I want to catch touch at any position of the view

Comment: It will return true for Intersection of views  from any direction.

Comment: But it only return true while topleft corner is touching the view

Answer (score 0):

You can check the whether the two view's frame are intersecting or not like this:

```
// assuming two views have outlets:
CGRect view1Frame = [view1 frame];
CGRect view2Frame = [view2 frame];
CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(view1Frame, view2Frame);
if(CGRectIsNull(intersection)) {
    // Not touching yet - null intersection
} else {
    // Touching! Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
CGRect bounds1 = [view1 convertRect:view1.bounds toView:nil];
CGRect bounds2 = [view2 convertRect:view2.bounds toView:nil];
BOOL viewsOverlap = CGRectIntersectsRect(bounds1, bounds2);
```

Comment: it's only return true when it's touch the top left corner of view 2

Answer (score 0):

For you need to start timer in which you need to check frame of the view.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkIntersect) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

check the below method for that

```
-(void) checkIntersect {

    CGRect f1 = [view1.layer.presentationLayer frame];
    CGRect f2 = [view2.layer.presentationLayer frame];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(f1, f2)) {
        NSLog(@"intersect both view");
    }
    else{
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(checkIntersect) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to handle your timer in such a way that when animation is completed it should stop calling this method. There are many ways to handle that.